# SQL - Put duplicates together

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I want to put all duplicates together and count how many times they appear.

This is my query:

```
SELECT Kursusnavn, Kursus_ID
FROM GK6.Kursus
INNER JOIN GK6.[Kursus _Studerende] on Kursus.ID = [Kursus _Studerende].Kursus_ID
ORDER BY Kursus_ID
```

And this is my
[image: output]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `SELECT Kursusnavn, Kursus_ID, COUNT(*) FROM ... GROUP BY Kursusnavn, Kursus_ID`

Comment: That worked! Thank you, and how do I order it, to get the ones with the highest count first?

Comment: What database are you using? `ORDER BY Count(*) DESC`;

Comment: Do you really have space in front of _ in field names?

Comment: That was a mistake. Using DESC did work. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT Kursusnavn, Kursus_ID, Count(*) AS CntID
FROM GK6.Kursus
INNER JOIN GK6.[Kursus_Studerende] ON Kursus.ID = [Kursus_Studerende].Kursus_ID
GROUP BY Kursusnavn, Kursus_ID
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

This is really a basic SQL. If you are using Access, it can easily be built with assistance of query designer. I presume other database platforms have some sort of similar tool.